# Is there any Parallel execution happen in sql server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Like the title : **Is there any parallel execution happen in sql server ?**.
My situation look like this:
Product table:

```
ProductId   Name   Amount
1           one    1
```

Update statement ( this statement can put in store procedure in sql or raw sql from .net code ):

```
Update Product set Amount = Amount - 1 where ProductId=1
```

So on my ui layout, i have a button to execute above update statement. When i realease this website to internet, assuming two user( or more ) go to my website **at the same time exactly** and click on this button **at the same time exactly**. So If this **Update statement execute** my **Amount column** will be less than 0 ( In this situation it will be -1 ). But My logic is **Amount column have to greater than or equal 0**. I know about Concurrency Editing data in sql and we have optimistic or pessimistic approach to handle this , As my knowledge Optimistic and Pessimistic approach just for overlapping time ( one executed just before other ). And i was wondering about how can i handle this problem if happen. Because i am working on shopping website and i want to announce a friendly message to user this product sold out or existing. I think i don't care either i use ADO.net or EF or other to do this, just situation beetween .net and sql work. Please give me some advice Or deep explaination for this situation because i google so much but have't found any thing look like this. Correct my information if i am incorrect because my english not good enough to understand some article that i refer! 
Thank you very much.

Comment: They're ALWAYS executed one before each other because even assuming SS accepts parallel requests they'll be synchronized (but executed in parallel). To detect such situations simplest way IMO is to use a timestamp. If a record you want to update has been updated after you read it then it means you have to notify that situation to users (classical example of a booking service).

Comment: You can add constraint for product also Look at transactions levels http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sq

Comment: @ Adriano I just wanna understand your idea clearly for this words: "even assuming SS accepts parallel requests they'll be synchronized (but executed in parallel)". You mean .net send parallel requests to sql, but sql will synchronize them and execute one by one look like the queue? And what is SS meaning!

Comment: @danisius Thanks for help me. You said add constraint for product. What kind of constraint you are talking? Is that trigger .

Comment: lloke here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with parallelism. Also without it, it could go wrong. The `UPDATE` statement is atomic, so they will always be executed serially (though there is no say which one goes first).

The simplest way to fix this, is to make a trigger on the `UPDATE` of that table, and throw an exception if the update is tried when already zero. Propagate that exception to the user to tell them to item is sold out. To help the customer better, remind him the item is *almost* sold out and he has to be quick.

Comment: Thanks for help me. What happen in sql if it receive two connection to do this update statement in the same time exactly ? Sorry for this extra question but just wanna make sure i understand how sql process in this situation!